# Replace DataFrame column index with MultiIndex

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a "flat" column index, ['Sample 1', 'Sample 2' ...], and I've constructed a MultiIndex that has two levels, the first of which having the same elements as my DataFrame's column index ('Sample 1' ...).   I want to replace the column index of my DataFrame with this MultiIndex, with each of the elements of the MultiIndex replacing the column index element that has the matching name.   So, the column headed with 'Sample 1' should now be headed with ('Sample 1', 'group x'), column with heading 'Sample 2' should now be ('Sample 2', 'group x'), and so forth.

For example, the DataFrame might look like:

```
         A    B    C
row1     1    2    3
row2     4    5    6
  :
rowN     7    8    9
```

And the MultiIndex would look like `[('A', 'G1'), ('B', 'G1'), ('C', 'G2')]`

With the end result looking like:

```
        G1   G1   G2
         A    B    C
row1     1    2    3
row2     4    5    6
  :
rowN     7    8    9
```

Seems like this should be a simple join or matching concatenation, but can't find the method (and/or keywords) to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign to the `columns` instance attribute

```
In [10]: df = DataFrame(randn(10, 3), columns=list('abc'))

In [11]: df.columns = [list('ABC'), df.columns]

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
       A      B      C
       a      b      c
0  2.320 -1.670  0.511
1  0.350 -1.877  0.627
2  1.671  0.347  1.328
3  0.896 -0.061  0.083
4  1.168  1.212 -1.127
5 -0.015  0.402  0.249
6 -0.576  0.898 -0.464
7 -0.939  0.198 -2.698
8 -0.767  0.532 -0.369
9  0.365  0.293 -0.676

In [13]: df.columns
Out[13]:
MultiIndex
[(u'A', u'a'), (u'B', u'b'), (u'C', u'c')]
```